# Check SMS and DIal support before Intent

Tags: android, android-intent, sms, tablet, phone-call

I have this code to send SMS via `Intent` and to call a number :

```
 public void Call(String s) {//Appeler
    String url = "tel:" + s;
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DIAL, Uri.parse(url));
    startActivity(intent);
}
public void Sms(String s){
    startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.fromParts("sms", s, null)));
}
```

it looks fine in my phone , no crash , but in my tablet which doesn't support SMS and call (doesn't have sim card and sms and dial app) the app crashes when calling these methods , so how to handle that exception ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must always check whether the is `Activity` which could handle your `Intent`

Suppose  **Skype** is install on tablet  that can  handle your **call** intent then launch intent

```
PackageManager packageManager = getPackageManager();
List activities = packageManager.queryIntentActivities(intent,
        PackageManager.MATCH_DEFAULT_ONLY);
boolean isIntentSafe = activities.size() > 0; 
if(isIntentSafe)
{
 // call Call(546) or Sms(1235)
}else{
// No activity is present  to handle  your intent
}
```

Also check this [link](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/sending.html)

Answer (score 1):

You can handle it like this:

```
public void Sms(String s){
    try {
        startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.fromParts("sms", s, null)));
    } catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) {
        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "No app for this", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
```